# List repeated values in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this table:

```
  |     A      |  B  |  C  |  D  |  E
1 | 2017-01-01 | AAA | BBB | CCC | DDD
2 | 2017-01-08 | AAA | BBB | BBB | CCC
3 | 2017-01-15 | BBB | AAA | DDD | DDD
4 | 2017-01-22 | CCC | BBB | CCC | BBB
```

Column A is always the previous date+7.
Columns B, C, D and E are based on data valitadion lists.

And I need to list, not only highlight, repeated values in each row (date).
I would like to insert the date in other sheet and below excel would list the repeated values.

Example:

```
2017-01-01  2017-01-08  2017-01-15  2017-01-22
            BBB         DDD         CCC
                                    BBB
```

If possible, it would be great to list, in a different column, which values are not present, keeping in mind I would only have "AAA, BBB, CCC and DDD".

Can someone please help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In **Columns F:J** do the following steps:

**1)** Transfer your original table into the below structure. 
 List your items `AAA,BBB,CCC,DDD` in **Column F**.

 Insert **counting numbers** from 0-3 in **Row 1**. 
In **Row 2** insert the dates from your original data by using this formula: `=OFFSET($A$1,G1,0)`
*(Formula goes into **Cell G2** and can be copied to the righ til **Cell J2**)*

**2)** In **G3** you insert this formula: 
 `=IF(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("B"&ROW($A$1)+G$1&":E"&ROW($E$1)+G$1),$F3)>1,$F3,"")` 
This formula you can **copy down** til **Row 6** and to the **right** til **Column J** and you will get the table below as a result.

```
  |  F  |     G      |     H      |     I      |      J       | 
1 |     |     0      |     1      |     2      |      3       |
2 |     | 2017-01-01 | 2017-01-08 | 2017-01-15 |  2017-01-22  |
3 | AAA |            |    BBB     |            |              |
4 | BBB |            |            |            |      BBB     |
5 | CCC |            |            |            |      CCC     |
6 | DDD |            |            |    DDD     |              |
```